# What's the difference when use Model Method with and without ()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If I have a Model to query `User`. And `User` has an externally associated table `Address`.

```
public function address() {
   return $this->hasOne('Address', 'id');
}
```

My doubt is below:
1.We can use `User->address` to get one data from `Address` table. We also can use `User->address()` to get data. I can `dd` them to get attributes What's the difference in the two ways?
2.When I use `User->address->first()`, it return the first data in `Address`, not the first data which matches the specified `id`.But I use `User->address()->first()` can get the correct data.

What's the reason of the above?

Comment: `$user` is a class, accessing `$user->address` accesses a public property on the class called `$address` where as `$user->address()` calls a method on the class. Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/FK1Jl

Comment: @naththedeveloper I have seen such a call method, does it require special settings? `User->address->first()`, it's result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you use `$user->address`, Laravel searches the `User` model for an address property or for a `getAddressAttribute()` method on the `User` model.

The `address()` method is only called when you use the `()` like `$user->address()`.

[Documentation on Laravel accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Eloquent relationships, in this case, `->address` is a shorthand for `->address()->first`, and it will "cache" the query result on your `User` object. So calling `->address` multiple times won't make additional database queries. Calling `->address()->first()` will make a database query every time.

Comment: But how does the result of `User->address->first()` come?In my case, it returns the first data of `Address` table. I have seen such a call method, does it require special settings?

Comment: You should not use `User->address->first()`. 
`User->address == User->address()->first()`, so calling `->first()` *again* on that would basically be the same as doing `User->address()->first()->first()`

Comment: OK! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

the main difference is as follows

`$model->address`

returns the relationship

```
$model->address()
```

returns an instance of the query builder which can be used for further constraint as follows

```
$model->address(function($query){
         $query->where('postcode', 'testpostcode');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know, `$model->address` get relational data item, `$model->address()` get relational model instance for custom statement. If you want use $model->address() you must use any query builder methods for get any data. etc. `$model->address()->where('status', true)->get()` `$model->address()->count()`